# Correctly setting up naxsi in LearningMode in Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, web, nginx, webserver, firewall

While activating [naxsi](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-naxsi-on-ubuntu-14-04) for my set up that uses nginx as reverse proxy with gunicorn, I've run into a misbehaving piece of code. Can someone help?

For now, I'm trying to turn naxsi on in `LearningMode`. I've added the following in the `http` section of my `nginx.conf`:

`include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;`

Also, I've changed `DeniedURL` value in naxsi.rules. So far so good.

My problem arises where I'm supposed to edit /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default" (as instructed in various [online](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-naxsi-on-ubuntu-14-04) [tutorials](http://www.greenacorn-websolutions.com/nginx/securing-your-app-with-nginx-naxsi.php)) to include include `/etc/nginx/naxsi.rules;` in root location.

My file in `sites-enabled` isn't called `default`, it's `myproject`. In `sites-available` though, I have `default` and `myproject` both (remember this, this has a role later in the question).

No worries so far. I add `include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules;` in `myproject`.

I next restart nginx via `sudo service nginx restart`. It **fails** to restart. I reverted. Then added the `default` file at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` (copied from `sites-available/default`), and added `/etc/nginx/naxsi.rules;` there.

Restarted again. Still failed. I reverted everything and restarted. The server is up and running, but I don't have naxsi.

What am I doing wrong? It's probably something basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to run `apt-get install nginx-naxsi` (in order to replace nginx-core) for this thing to iron itself out. It worked!